# Can I create a colour scheme for a custom chapter and the apply it to other chapters?

Tags: warhammer-40k

So what I mean is, could I make a colour scheme for my Space Marines and then use that same colour scheme for Grey Knights or Adeptus Mechanicus or Astra Militarum?

Comment: FWIW you might consider doing "variants" of your color schemes for different factions... So they tie together, but are also distinct.

Answer (score 4):

You can honestly play the game with unpainted miniatures, nothing prevents you from using your own color schemes, and many people do, though if you intend to be using these forces together in a mixed imperial army, it's best your color scheme between the different subgroups of your army is clear, so effects don't accidentally get applied to a unit from the wrong arm of the Imperium of Man.

Coloring a Mechanicus unit the Yellow and Black of your Imperial Fists could cause you to accidentally apply First Captain Lysander's Icon of Obstinacy to them, when it only applies to his own chapter's units.